# .htaccess - redirect domain.com and www.domain.com - to www.domain.com/en

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a language setup on my pages, so that my root page will always be domain.com/en

So what im looking to do is redirect all queries to domain.com and www.domain.com to domain.com/en.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If domain.com and www.domain.com have the same root folder, put .htaccess there with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey Cheery. I just tried it out - it didnt seem to work as supposed.

What happens is that I get redirected to www.domain.com/en/index.php - and index.php doesnt exist there

Comment: @user1231561  And what did you want? It should redirect `/somerequest` to `/en/somerequest`

Comment: The following seems to work - however only for domain.com - and I cant seem to re-use it for making the rewrite for www.domain.com.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/en/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: @user1231561 Do not jump from one way to another. You can not use the same rule for www domain is it might create an infinite loop of redirects. Show me what kind of request you have done and what result did you get.

Comment: With your example domain.com and www.domain.com redirected to - www.domain.com/en/index.php. And that just threw me a 404 page could not be found. Im just looking to make it redirect to domain.com/en/

Comment: @user1231561 My answer has nothing to do with index.php as you can see from the rules. It happens because your initial request looks like domain.com/index.php and it is forwarded to www.domain.com/en/index.php. If your initial request was domain.com then check other things on your server which might forward the initial request to index.php. It has nothing to do with the rules I wrote.

Comment: @user1231561  or do you want to redirect just the request to the web root? `/` to `/en/` and not the `/somerequest` to `/en/somerequest`?

Comment: Exactly - just looking to redirect the web root whether it being with or withour www. to /en/ :)

Comment: @user1231561 You should state it clearly, try `RewriteRule ^$ http://www.domain.com/en/ [R=301,L]` It will affect only / requests, but I thought that you already had some site structure before and wanted to update all previously existed URLs to a new one.

Comment: Thanks Cheery - that seemed to do the trick! Very appreciated :)

Comment: @user1231561 If that is what you need you can remove RewriteCond, it will not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you understand that it is not ethical to update your answer with an answer of another person?